# output is not going to stdout

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I have some executable which is a command processor. I'm trying to capture its response to commands. I use python subprocesses.

Below is my script:

```
import subprocess

# Open the subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('comproc.exe', \
stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)

# Write a command
proc.stdin.write('help cfg_open\n')

# Close the input stream so the subprocess knows to exit
proc.stdin.close()

data = 0
while data!="":
    data = proc.stdout.readline()
    print data

# Wait for subprocess to exit
exit_status = proc.wait()
```

The output ("Welcome to command proc (c) 2015 ...") before I issue the "help cfg_open" is captured, while the response to "help cfg_open" is not.
The stderr is captured correctly if I issue some non-existing command.

Redirecting via cmd is working excellent:

```
c:\>comproc.exe >1.txt
help cfg_open
exit
c:\>
```

I get the whole output in 1.txt.

Would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Your posted code results in a "file not found" error.

Comment: @Prune The code is working and executable. comproc.exe is a part of big development environment. My question here is more general - what can be the reasons for this strange behavior?  Thanks!

Comment: The Python code lacks the `exit` you seem to type in the cmd example‽ Also there might be buffering between the two processes.

Comment: @BlackJack I tried with the exit. It didn't help. I also tried flush()ing. No result either.